# Recursividade usando Python

Tags: python, funções, recursão

estou tentando criar uma função recursiva que receba um número inteiro positivo N e imprima todos os números pares de 0 até N em ordem crescente.

Eu só estou conseguindo fazer o contrário, isto é, imprimir os números em decrescente. Abaixo vai estar o código que construi, mas ele não realiza a tarefa deseja. Desde já, quero agradecer pela ajuda e atenção de todos que vão cooperar.

```
def sequencia_de_numero(number):
    if number == 0:
        print(number)
    else:
        if number % 2 == 0:
            print(number)
            return sequencia_de_numero(number -1)
        else:
            return sequencia_de_numero(number - 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Fazendo a chamada da função dela mesma antes do print funciona:

```py
def sequencia_de_numero(number):
    if number < 0:
        return -1
    
    sequencia_de_numero(number - 1)
    
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number, end=' ')
```

Depois basta chamar a função normalmente:

```py
sequencia_de_numero(40)
```

Answer (score -2):

Aqui está um exemplo de uma função recursiva:

```py
def factorial(x):
    if x < 3:
        return x
    else:
        return x * factorial(x - 1)
```

Mas se você quer fazer uma sequência crescente, não tem necessidade de usar funções, use um loop `for`:

```py
for i in range(0, 42, 2): #O terceiro número na função range é o passo, se você usar 2, só vai ter números pares
    print(i)
```

Comment: E qual é o intuito de um exemplo de fatorial recursivo nesta pergunta?

Comment: Porque esta função é recursiva, e demonstra recursão